# How to include all the contents of a file in the <body> using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I want to have a separate file that holds some javascript functions. When XSLT processes my application, i want it to output all the contents of this file to the HTML. I do not want to reference a library, but instead have all the functions inside inside my html.

I know of `<xsl:include>` but i cannot include anything inside  or `<body>` tags.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Well assuming your file (e.g. `scripts.xml`) to be included is XML e.g. has a contents like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function foo() { ... }
function bar() { ... }
...
</script>
```

then in XSLT you can simply use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('scripts.xml')/script"/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

If that does not help then you need to explain in more details what kind of file you have, which XSLT version you use (XSLT 2.0 can also read in non-XML  plain text files like Javascript code).

[edit]
Here is an XSLT 2.0 sample using unparsed-text (requires an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon or AltovaXML):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         <xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text('file.js')"/>
      </script>

    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It is a JavaScript file (.js). I am using version 1.0 - could you show me how to read non-xml plain text files with version 2.0, and write them to the HTML?

Comment: With XSLT 2.0 there is the function http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-unparsed-text, I will edit my post to show an example.

Comment: Do you know if using this function with Visual Studio is possible? I set the <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"> but i am getting the following error: 'unparsed-text()' is an unknown XSLT function.

Comment: visual studio uses xsl 1 and xpath 1. You can call it what you want, but visual studio won't recognise it as it is an XSLT2 function

Comment: Microsoft does not have an XSLT 2.0 processor supporting XSLT 2.0 with functions like `unparsed-text`. You need to use third party solutions like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime.

Answer (score 1):

**Use the [`unparsed-text()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#function-unparsed-text) function to read the content of a text file.**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:sequence select="unparsed-text('YourFile.js')"/>
      </body>
     </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```